# How to launch app at the same time on Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two apps, A and B.
I want to call B by A.
My code in A is as below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.bapp","com.example.bapp.BActivity"));
intent.putExtra ("test2abc", "abctest2");
startActivity(intent);
```

And B's intent filter in manifest as below:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="ACTION_BACKCALL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

But it will close B before launch B while B had opened.
I find below code to open *.txt file. This will open two txt reader app at the same time.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimetype);
startActivity(inte
```

nt);

How can I arrive that?

Comment: do you want to launch B without having it restart? or A and B should be active at same time?

Comment: I want original B and b Called by A run at the same time.

Comment: While A launch B, and pressed "home" button to desktop, then I click the A app's icon. It will show the B which had launch.

Comment: so you have 2 apps A and B. B can be launched separately and by A. So when you press the A apps icon you don't want to see B rather A all the time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to try  **android:launchMode="singleInstance"** and 
**android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"** while defining launcher activity.

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.sampleMediaPlayer"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

For Activity A.

Answer (score 4):

hey i found this code snippet [Launch an application from another application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application) which will work for you
set the address of the application which you want to launch

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```